# Aggregate data using each() with reshape2::dcast

Tags: r, aggregate-functions, plyr, reshape

I'm usually using `reshape` package to aggregate some data (d'uh), usually with `plyr`, because of its uber-awesome function `each`. Recently, I received a suggestion to switch to `reshape2` and try it out, and now I can't seem to use `each` wizardry anymore.

#### reshape

```
> m <- melt(mtcars, id.vars = c("am", "vs"), measure.vars = "hp")
> cast(m, am + vs ~ variable, each(min, max, mean, sd))
  am vs hp_min hp_max   hp_mean    hp_sd
1  0  0    150    245 194.16667 33.35984
2  0  1     62    123 102.14286 20.93186
3  1  0     91    335 180.83333 98.81582
4  1  1     52    113  80.57143 24.14441
```

#### reshape2

```
require(plyr)
> m <- melt(mtcars, id.vars = c("am", "vs"), measure.vars = "hp")
> dcast(m, am + vs ~ variable, each(min, max, mean, sd))
Error in structure(ordered, dim = ns) : 
  dims [product 4] do not match the length of object [16]
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In fs[[i]](x, ...) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In fs[[i]](x, ...) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

I wasn't into mood to comb this down, as my previous code works like a charm with `reshape`, but I'd really like to know:

1. is it possible to use `each` with `dcast`?
2. is it advisable to use `reshape2` at all? is `reshape` deprecated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer to your first question appears to be **no**. Quoting from `?reshape2:::dcast`:

> If the combination of variables you supply does not uniquely identify
>   one row in the original data set, you will need to supply an
>   aggregating function, fun.aggregate. This function should take a
>   vector of numbers and return a single summary statistic.

A look at Hadley's github page for [reshape2](https://github.com/hadley/reshape/blob/master/README.md) suggests that he knows this functionality was removed, but seems to think it's better done in **plyr**, presumably with something like:

```
ddply(m,.(am,vs),summarise,min = min(value),
                           max = max(value),
                           mean = mean(value),
                           sd = sd(value))
```

or if you really want to keep using `each`:

```
ddply(m,.(am,vs),function(x){each(min,max,mean,sd)(x$value)})
```

Comment: Yeah, I saw that, I thought that there was some hackish way to still accomplish that. =) Thanks! What's the status of `reshape` anyway? Is it deprecated?!

Comment: @aL3xa Not that I know of. But Hadley has written so many packages that he can probably only maintain a certain number of the regularly. My impression was that he would move `reshape` functionality back into `reshape2` based on user feedback. So maybe letting him know would be best?

Comment: Yeah, @joran, I guess you're right. I may use plyr too, if it's gonna be any faster. Will have to do some tests...

Comment: From the reshape readme: Reshape2 is a reboot of the reshape package. It's been over five years since the first release of the package, and in that time I've learned a tremendous amount about R programming, and how to work with data in R. Reshape2 uses that knowledge to make a new package for reshaping data that is much more focussed and much much faster.

This version improves speed at the cost of functionality, so I have renamed it to reshape2 to avoid causing problems for existing users. Based on user feedback I may reintroduce some of these features.